# Best practice for checking for an enum flag

Tags: c#, .net, enums, enum-flags

I noticed these two patterns for checking for an enum flag:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum PurchaseType
{
    None = 0,
    SalePrice = 2,
    RegularPrice = 4,
    Clearance = 8,
    CreditCard = 16
}

public void Test()
{
    PurchaseType type = PurchaseType.Clearance;
    type |= PurchaseType.CreditCard;

    // Practice 1
    if ((type & PurchaseType.Clearance) == PurchaseType.Clearance)
    {
        // Clearance item handling
    }

    // Practice 2
    if ((type & PurchaseType.CreditCard) != 0)
    {
        // Credit card item handling   
    }
}
```

Of the two ways of checking for an enum flag, which one is better w.r.t performance, readability, code health, and any other considerations I should make?

Thanks,
Mohammed

Comment: Better for what? Readability? Performance? Phase of the moon? Something else?

Comment: I vote for practice 1.  How would you test for `PurchaseType.None` with practice 2?  Edit: I guess you could do (type & PurchaseType.None) == 0, but then now your checks are not really consistent.

Comment: @Tung Er, `None` is not a flag that can be tested for. `type & PurchaseType.None` is `0` for all values of `type`. You can never test for `None` so there's no point in worrying about how to do what cannot be done and is never done.

Comment: @Oded: The question is open-ended ("which one is better and why") so that other aspects to consider like "performance" and "phase of the moon" can be highlighted. :)

Comment: That makes it a _poor fit_ for Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @Oded - the trouble with people being against "unanswerable" "which one is better and why" questions, is that it is not always clear it is unanswerable when it is asked. The OP could have asked this question and had everyone agree "Practice n is better for the following reason, don't do practice m". This is actually a fair question. The fact the answer is actually "there is no compelling reason to chose between" them doesn't negate this question at all IMHO. In addition to this, it has given rise to an enlightening conversation around reflection in HasFlag - which is itself also v. useful.

Comment: @Oded: I am not sure if I agree that this is a "poor fit" for SO. I don't see how this comment in the FAQ "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." can be applied here. Are you referring to this statement? If so, do you really think that this comment also applies to my "open-ended" question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

.Net 4 introduces a [`HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method that determines whether one or more bit fields are set in the current instance, this is by far the best practice:

```
type.HasFlag(PurchaseType.CreditCard);  // true
```

Comment: That looks easier to use. I saw this [connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/554908/enum-hasflag-tremendously-bad-performance) regarding performance. I wonder if this was fixed in 4.0.

Comment: A [blog entry](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2011/01/28/enum-hasflag-good-or-bad.aspx) regarding this and bad performance. It seems that this is not just some simple syntactic sugar. This method seems to employ reflection according to this post.

Comment: I see many upvotes for this answer and now am curious. Let's say that there was a perf penalty for using this over others. Would readbability win here over performance?

Comment: You want us to answer whether or not the performance penalty is significant for you?!! Only you can answer that.

Comment: @MohammedAli - If your HasFlag is not performance critical I would be inclined to go with readability. However - I've got to be honest - until I saw the link to the blog article I didn't realise there was any potential issue. Now I look in reflector, I see it does indeed use reflection, to check that the two enum types match.

Comment: If performance is an issue, an alternative to making your code unreadable is to consolidate it into a `HasFlag` method for each enum type you'd like to compare.  If you use a different method name or signature, you can even make it an extension method, e.g. `public static bool HasFlagFast(this PurchaseType v, PurchaseType f)
        {
            return (v & f) == f;
        }` and called using `type.HasFlagFast(PurchaseType.CreditCard);`

Comment: Careful using this pattern with None==0, as `type.HasFlag(PurchaseType.None)` will always evaluate to true, when you probably mean `type == PurchaseType.None`

Answer (score 2):

I would choose the first one:

```
if ((type & PurchaseType.Clearance) == PurchaseType.Clearance)
{
    // Clearance item item handling
}
```

cause it clearly clams that you're checking for `Clearance` type presence.

Comment: Hmm, I don't like that much. I can see duplication. If you changed `Clearance` to one of the other flags but forgot to do it in both locations, then your code would compile, but it would not do what you want. `!=0` wins for me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: agree (on dupplicate), but like the clear esplicit declaration.

Comment: @David: I actually made this exact mistake when typing my question!

Comment: @MohammedAli Sounds like you have your answer then. At least out of the two candidates in the question.

Comment: @David: I don't see a way of accepting your comment as an answer :).

Answer (score 1):

I personally would always prefer the clear readability of `HasFlag`.

However, out of the two options in the question I think `!=0` is safer because it has no duplication. If you use your alternative then it's all too easy when maintenence coding to change one of of the flags and forget to change the other. And then you end up with this

```
if ((type & PurchaseType.Clearance) == PurchaseType.CreditCard)
```

Comment: in the context of performance. is there a cast involved in using the != 0 check?

Comment: How could comparing against 0 have performance implications?

Comment: Does the 0 value have to be casted up during the check? If so, is it any worse than the other option in my question?

Comment: Why would a cast cost processor time? Casts between ints and enums are dealt with at compile time.

Comment: I see so both options seem equally performant.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer `(type & PurchaseType.CreditCard) != 0` because if you want to check for more than one bit then the right hand side becomes cumbersome. I trust in bit operations that the above will only be true if and only if the bit(s) is set.